# How to read multilevel json in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

```python
**Json Structure is -:**
aa.json

[[{"foo":"test1"},{"foo1":"test21"}],
[{"foo":"test2"},{"foo1":"test22"}],
[{"foo":"test3"},{"foo1":"test23"}]]
```

Code to read DataFrame:

```python
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

a=sqlContext.read.option('multiline',"true").json('aa.json');
a.show()
+----+----+
| foo|foo1|
+----+----+
|null|null|
+----+----+

a.printSchema()
root
 |-- foo: string (nullable = true)
 |-- foo1: string (nullable = true)
```

Here are the lines for reading this json, it can able to parse schema but not the data.

Comment: The format of your JSON file is not something that's supported (AFAIK) by the current spark file reading methods. If you can't change your file (remove the outermost brackets and the trailing commas), you can parse this as a text file and use regular expressions to massage the data into the desired format.

Comment: yes, @pault you are right, I am able to read via using textFile, but my JSON size is too big approx 1 GB, so regular expressions option is too costly for me. 
for now, what I did, I read this as a textFile then convert this RDD to Python JSON by using the collect function, which is also a costly operation.
is there any good approach?

Answer (score 1):

Applying some regular expressions and converting to `rdd` may work for you here.

First read the file using `textFile`:

```python
a=spark.read.option('multiline',"true").text('aa.json')
a.show(truncate=False)
#+-------------------------------------+
#|value                                |
#+-------------------------------------+
#|[[{"foo":"test1"},{"foo1":"test21"}],|
#|[{"foo":"test2"},{"foo1":"test22"}], |
#|[{"foo":"test3"},{"foo1":"test23"}]] |
#+-------------------------------------+
```

Now we can use `pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace` to remove the extra square brackets and the trailing comma from each line:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace
a = a.select(regexp_replace("value", "(^\[(?=\[))|((?<=\])\]$)|(,$)", "").alias("value"))
a.show(truncate=False)
#+-----------------------------------+
#|value                              |
#+-----------------------------------+
#|[{"foo":"test1"},{"foo1":"test21"}]|
#|[{"foo":"test2"},{"foo1":"test22"}]|
#|[{"foo":"test3"},{"foo1":"test23"}]|
#+-----------------------------------+
```

The pattern here a logical or of the following patterns:

- `^\[(?=\[)`: Start of string followed by `[[` (the second `[` is a non-capturing group)
- `(?<=\])\]$`: `]]` at the end of the string (the first`]` is a non-capturing group)
- `,$`: A comma at the end of the string

Any patterns that match are replaced by an empty string.

Now convert to `rdd` and use `json.loads` to parse your rows into lists of dictionaries. Then [merge all of these dictionaries together into one dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-to-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression) and call the `pyspark.sql.Row` constructor. Finally call `.toDF` to convert back to a DataFrame.

```python
# From `How to merge two dictionaries in a single expression?`
# This code works for python 2 and 3
def merge_two_dicts(x, y):
    z = x.copy()   # start with x's keys and values
    z.update(y)    # modifies z with y's keys and values & returns None
    return z

import json
from pyspark.sql import Row
from functools import reduce 

a.rdd.map(lambda x: Row(**reduce(merge_two_dicts, json.loads(x['value'])))).toDF().show()
#+-----+------+
#|  foo|  foo1|
#+-----+------+
#|test1|test21|
#|test2|test22|
#|test3|test23|
#+-----+------+
```

**References**:

- [How to merge two dictionaries in a single expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-to-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression)

Comment: Hi @pault thanks for replying but my use case is beyond that.schema can be  like this.
[[{"foo":"test1","foo1":"test12","test":[{"hello":"hi1"}]},{"foo1":"test21","foo2":"test13","test":[{"hello":"hi1"}]}],
[{"foo":"test2","foo1":"test13","test":[{"hello":"hi2"}]},{"foo1":"test22","foo1":"test12","test":[{"hello":"hi2"}]}]]

it will not work in that case.

Comment: HI, @pault Can you answer this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53916299/pyspark-streaming-process-failed-with-await-termination